# Custom directory for mongodb data

Tags: mongodb

I specified a different directory for my mongodb data in the mongodb conf file:

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /home/psr/data/mongodb
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2024-03-01T09:14:42.914-06:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"Location28596: Unable to determine status of lock file in the data directory /home/psr/data/mongodb: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied [system:13]: \"/home/psr/data/mongodb/mongod.lock\""}}
```

Here are the permissions of the old and the new lock files:

OLD:

```
-rw---x--- 1 mongodb mongodb 0 Mar  1 08:31 /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

NEW:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mongodb mongodb 0 Mar  1 08:53 data/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the right permissions on each directory leading to that path.

Comment: Thank you @mustaccio!

Comment: Maybe it is not so smart to store the data in your (personal) home directory. Usually `mongod` process runs as user `mongodb` which by default has no access to your home directory. Better use a generic folder, e.g. `/var/lib/mongodb/` - looks like you did this, but you played around with different folders.

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit. My /var/ directory has very little space. If you could tell me a workaround for moving some partition from my home folder to var folder, it would be really helpful. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Talk to your Linux admin to get more space